# Getting the exception org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following exception when running automation using selenium

```
Jul 27, 2023 11:20:18 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have already added `options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");`
I am still getting the exception. Any reasons why?

> WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
> ChromeDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).setup();   ChromeOptions
> options = new ChromeOptions();
> options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");   WebDriver driver =
> new ChromeDriver(options);